# Karma Test case - ScrollTop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I am unable to do karma Test case for the following snippet.

"document.body.scrollTop" is always 0 and I am unable to change the scrollTop value. Can you please suggest me how do I change the value of scrollTop?

```
$window.onscroll = function() {
    var status = document.body.scrollTop > document.body.scrollHeight;
    if(status) 
    console.log("working fine - tested");
}
```

Thanks,
Raja K

Comment: Is your `scrollHeight` non-0? Does your document.body have a height? What browser is karma using? One thing that has worked for me has been to give the document in the test a non-0 height and an `overflow` of `scroll` to make sure that it is scrollable.